# How to fill with space for pretty logger messages?

Tags: kotlin, logging, whitespace

Is there a way to fill with spaces after the variable `$nameIdDocument` so that the 2nd variable (`${resultPreventRequest.documentType}`) always shows up at the spot ?

I like to have logger messages aligned vertically. I would like to have PASSEPORT and RESIDENCE_PERMIT start at the same position.

Here the code I execute, and the image attached is what is printed by the logger.

```
LOGGERCTRLONE.info("Correctly Read document | doctype found : $nameIdDocument | ${resultPreventRequest.documentType}")
```

[logger output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbS65.png)

I tried the java syntax with `%s-20` but it does nothing, regardless where it is positioned.

I have looked up online and there is no subject about this alignment problem in Kotlin.

Comment: Bear in mind that logs aren't _always_ viewed in a monospaced font, so it's not guaranteed to line up as you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java syntax to use with formatting would be  like `%-20s`. The conversion type, `s` in this case, always goes last.

```
fun main() {
    println("%-25s | %-22s | %s".format("Correctly Read document", "some document.xyz", "some document type"))
    println("%-25s | %-22s | %s".format("Incorrectly Read document", "another document2.xyz", "another document type"))
}
```

Prints

```
Correctly Read document   | some document.xyz      | some document type
Incorrectly Read document | another document2.xyz  | another document type
```

Kotlin doesn't provide any built-in logging feature. The logging library you're using might have a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Thx for the advice, I looked up about the logger I'm using, and it is from the slf4j package.

And it is possible to add spacing for this logger. I found a way to solve my problem :   

`LOGGERCTRLONE.info("Correctly Read document | doctype found : {} | {}", String.format("%-30s", nameIdDocument), String.format( "${resultPreventRequest.documentType}"))`